# WiFi dropping with realtek card on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I'm on a fresh install of Linux Mint 17.2. Since I've installed I've noticed my WiFi connection drops but doesn't disconnect. The WiFi works fine on Windows. I'm unable to ping any server or load any site for the duration. It seems to happen at random intervals.

```
nanor@teabags ~ $ inxi -N
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v1.0 Gigabit Ethernet driver: atl1c 
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter driver: rtl8192ce

nanor@teabags ~ $ dmesg |tail --lines=100
[   11.059457] sound hdaudioC0D2:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   11.059458] sound hdaudioC0D2:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   11.059459] sound hdaudioC0D2:    inputs:
[   11.059460] sound hdaudioC0D2:      Rear Mic=0x18
[   11.059462] sound hdaudioC0D2:      Front Mic=0x19
[   11.059463] sound hdaudioC0D2:      Line=0x1a
[   11.059464] sound hdaudioC0D2:      CD=0x1c
[   11.069610] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[   11.069669] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[   11.069712] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[   11.069753] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input16
[   11.331752] rtl8192ce: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
[   11.399985] usb 2-1.2: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4096), cval->res is probably wrong.
[   11.399988] usb 2-1.2: [11] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = 0/4096/1
[   11.404551] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   11.404553] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   11.404555] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   11.407743] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   11.583388] device-mapper: multipath: version 1.7.0 loaded
[   11.611364] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   11.611540] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   11.721227] gpio_ich: GPIO from 180 to 255 on gpio_ich
[   12.530107] init: failsafe main process (652) killed by TERM signal
[   12.555650] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   12.555653] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   12.555654] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   12.555656] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   12.555657] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   12.555658] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   12.555659] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   12.555661] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   12.954767] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[   12.954769] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   12.958135] fglrx: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   12.977588] <6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 7735 MBytes.
[   12.977690] <6>[fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 6810 revision: 0 count: 1
[   12.977869] <6>[fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0xce00, size: 0x100
[   12.978009] <6>[fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[   12.978023] <6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 15.20.2 [Feb 27 2015] with 1 minors
[   13.161531] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
[   13.161548] work still pending
[   15.834192] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   15.834207] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   15.834208] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.834213] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.834214] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.834221] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.900659] init: cups main process (988) killed by HUP signal
[   15.900667] init: cups main process ended, respawning
[   15.973743] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   15.973752] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   15.973756] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   16.029694] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   16.029703] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   16.029709] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   18.582172] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   18.587116] atl1c 0000:05:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   18.600970] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   18.719227] init: samba-ad-dc main process (1138) terminated with status 1
[   18.783580] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   18.786332] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1301) terminated with status 1
[   18.786340] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   19.864769] wlan0: authenticate with e4:f4:c6:b8:a8:e8
[   19.876333] wlan0: send auth to e4:f4:c6:b8:a8:e8 (try 1/3)
[   19.881784] wlan0: authenticated
[   19.884017] wlan0: associate with e4:f4:c6:b8:a8:e8 (try 1/3)
[   19.907144] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e4:f4:c6:b8:a8:e8 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   19.907266] wlan0: associated
[   19.907273] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   19.907344] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: GB
[   19.908928] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: GB
[   19.908931] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   19.908932] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   19.908933] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   19.908935] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   19.908936] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   19.908937] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[   19.908938] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[   21.400732] fglrx_pci 0000:01:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   21.401281] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1352
[   21.401379] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1353
[   21.401477] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1354
[   21.401556] <6>[fglrx] IRQ 45 Enabled
[   21.411078] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[   21.411080] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f7b4000, size:4000 
[   21.411081] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f7b8000, size:548000 
[   21.411082] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:7ffee000, size:12000 
[   29.362062] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1840) terminated with status 1
[   38.201222] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xf
[   38.201233] ata2.00: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[   38.201242] ata2.00: hard resetting link
[   38.311635] usb 2-1.2: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1
[   38.312636] usb 2-1.2: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-32)
[   40.428941] ata2.01: hard resetting link
[   41.457240] ata2.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   41.468037] ata2.00: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[   41.468055] ata2.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
[   41.468105] ata2: EH complete
[  578.056361] systemd-hostnamed[5463]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[  920.108966] systemd-hostnamed[5584]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

So far I've ignored IPv6 to no avail. I also caught a bit of someone with the same problem who had a Realtek card. He was instructed to write the following in `/etc/modprobe.d/` with a filename matching his Realtek card, I think. I did something similar:

```
nanor@teabags ~ $ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ce.conf 
options rtl8192ce fwlps=N ips=N
```

I've restarted and this doesn't seem to make any difference. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Based on `SError: { CommWake DevExch }`, it seems you've some hard-disk issues, see: [Mysterious Hard Disk Failure?](http://askubuntu.com/q/109180/78223). So probably you need to change your HDD (could be its driver), or it conflict with the other device.

Comment: I've seen this happen before on an Intel vPro laptop, but only when the lid was closed. The problem eventually fixed itself (I think?).

Comment: @Nanor Try: [Fluctuating wifi signal and random disconnects rtl8192ce](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137120/21471).

Comment: Try also post more info, as your logs doesn't contain info when it's actually dropped. The log which you included is only during the boot time.

Comment: @Nanor Try changing your router to `802.11bg` only. See also: [Wifi Drops and Reconnects with UBUNTU 14.04 (Realtek RTL8188)](http://askubuntu.com/q/500310/78223).

Comment: @Nanor Try also the following settings instead: `options rtl8192ce ips=0 fwlps=0`.

Comment: @kenorb I'm unable to change the router to `bg` either through the router's control panel on `192.168.0.1` or through terminal with `sudo iwconfig wlan0 modu 11g`.

What do I do with the new options you've tried? I've entered `modprobe rtl8192c-common` into terminal. Is that it?

Comment: @Nanor Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ce.conf` and change the options which you've pasted into these one, but actually these looks pretty the same (assuming `N` = `0`).

Comment: I'm afraid it still isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an, Linux compatible USB wireless adapters.
This solved my problem on my old laptop.
There are few brands that work great, here is a short list

TP-Link TL-WN722N 150Mbps High Gain Wireless USB Adapter

TRENDNET TEW 664UB

and there are more you can look on google for models.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to fix this rather than buy a new card but I fear I have no choice.